# Angular 6 @ngx-translate translation from REST API

Tags: angular, rest, ngx-translate

I'm currently trying to implement a translation service using @ngx-translate on Angular6 calling a REST API.

I've defined my own TranslateLoader with getTranslation method. On application initialization, this loader is called and retrieve the json stream from API.
Problem is when I try to switch to another language the TranslateLoader is not called back.
Is there a good sample for this @ngx-translate use case ?

Comment: Have you check the http-loader ? https://github.com/ngx-translate/http-loader ?

Comment: I'm using something like this : class CustomLoader implements TranslateLoader {
    getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.of({KEY: 'value'});
    }
}

Comment: It's not from an external API. Is all your translations are in JSON files in your project ?

Comment: All translation come from our API in JSON format